# Uncaught Invariant Violation: query option is required. You must specify your GraphQL document in the query option

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm trying to get a list of countries from a `graphql` server in my react app. The `getAllCountry` query works fine on playground but whenever I call the same query on the app, I get the following **errors**:

> 1. "query option is required. You must specify your GraphQL document in the query option" (error as seen on screen),

> 2. "Uncaught Invariant Violation: query option is required. You must specify your GraphQL document in the query option." (error on console)

Here's what my code looks like:

```js
// gql query inside gqlQueries.js

export const GET_ALL_COUNTRIES = gql`
  query getAllCountry {
    getAllCountry {
      name
      id
      countryCode
      currencyCode
    }
  }
`;

// calling the query

 import { queries as gql } from "./gqlQueries";

 const getAllCountries = () => {
    client
      .query({
        query: gql.GET_ALL_COUNTRIES
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

I'm very sure my client is configured correctly because I have other queries in my `gqlQueries.js` file and they all work fine except this particular one (`getAllCountry`).

Comment: network request body?

Comment: You mean I should post the how the network request body looks like?

Comment: You can rename the export, but you need to remove the part of accessing the query through the `gql.` variable. Like `import { GET_ALL_COUNTRIES as query } from ...` and use just `query`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried importing the query directly? e.g.

```
 import { GET_ALL_COUNTRIES } from "./gqlQueries";

 const getAllCountries = () => {
    client
      .query({
        query: GET_ALL_COUNTRIES
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

I had a similar issue and it was the syntax within the .query method. Not sure if the way you're importing it is causing an issue (although maybe not if you've done the same for your other queries).

Comment: Yes, after a lot of googling and asking for help, I tried importing the query directly and surprisingly, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the gql here:

```
.query({
    query: gql.GET_ALL_COUNTRIES
  })
```

It should be like this:

```
.query({
    query: GET_ALL_COUNTRIES
  })
```

gql is already inside the const:

```
export const GET_ALL_COUNTRIES = gql`
  query getAllCountry {
    getAllCountry {
      name
      id
      countryCode
      currencyCode
    }
  }`;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).